# Show Treeview only on item select from combobox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application/MVVM Pattern and it has a combobox and a treeview control. 
What I wanted to do is to show the treeview control only when i select an item from the combobox.

For example : I have a Property called SelectedTransactionName

```
      private string _selectedTransactionWsName;
        public string SelectedTransactionName
        {
            set
            {
                if (_selectedTransactionWsName == value) return;
                this._selectedTransactionWsName = value;

                InitializaMessageElement();
            }
            get
            {
                return this._selectedTransactionWsName;
            }

        }
```

my InitializaMessageElement method will show matching transaction name to the selected item. But now I don't want to show the treeview on page load only when i do a select on the combobox.
On page load I want my window to show only the combobox.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view model can contain a calculated boolean property to which your `TreeView` binds its `Visibility` property, e.g:

```
public bool IsTransactionNameSelected
{
    get
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectedTransactionWsName);
    }
}
```

You could then notify property change in the setter of the `SelectedTransactionName`:

```
set
{
   if (_selectedTransactionWsName == value) return;
   this._selectedTransactionWsName = value;
   InitializaMessageElement();

   this.NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => this.IsTransactionNameSelected);
}
```

Then you can bind your `TreeView` `Visibility` property using the supplied `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`:

```
<TreeView 
    Visibility="{Binding IsTransactionNameSelected, 
                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" ...
```